# Prove Limit in Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

[image: 9.12]

I know how to prove each step of the hint, but I don't see how the last step helps to prove lim S$_n$ = 0. Can someone break down the idea behind this hint for me?

Edit: I read my proof again, and I am not sure if this is a legit proof. I set a = L + $\epsilon$, but I can't guarantee that a < 1. Any thoughts?
[image: proof]

Comment: Since $0 < a <1,$ $\lim a^{n-N} = 0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $0<a<1$, you must have $a^{n-N}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty.$  So that squeezes $\mid s_n \mid$ down to $0$.